# Counting expired dates

Tags: excel, sum, counting

I'm doing a skills matrix for work to show if people need refresher training after 3 years but also  show they are training to the latest procedures.
Cells turn red if training hasn't been refreshed in 3 years or if they are trained to the old version on the procedure.

[image]

Cells D3 to F3 turn red is they are blank, over 3 years old or earlier than cell C3.

Cell G4 reads:

```
=COUNTBLANK(D3:F3)+COUNTIF(D3:F3,"<"&$C3)+COUNTIF(D3:F3,"<"&TODAY()-1095)
```

My problem is because cell E3 is earlier than C3 but also over three years old, it is counting it as `2`. Giving me a 'To do' as `4` instead of `3`.

Can I possibly get it to only count `1` even if there are two problems with the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at this backwards. If everyone was blank, expired or out-of-date then the result is **3**. You want to reduce that by the people that are within the 3 year period AND are up-to-date.

```
=3-countifs(D3:F3, ">="&edate(today(), -36), D3:F3, ">="&C3)
```

The [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) the result by the number of qualified people. The [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) is an easier (and slightly more accurate) method of asking for a date 3 years (or 36 months) ago.